# in python i need to print "no results" if none are found

Tags: python

In searching a python file, i need to be able to print "no results" if no results are found

```
**strong text**elif x.upper()=="Y":
    k=input("Enter the 1st letter of the name (upper-Case):")
    y=open("Names.txt","r")
    for i in y.readlines():
        if k.upper() in i:
            print (i[:-1])
        #need option if no search results are found
```

Comment: So do it. What is stopping you?

Comment: create a flag if found(inside your `if` something like `found=True`) and if the flag is false print 'no results' outside of the `for`

Comment: Another option would be to add an else clause to the for loop and break after the print statement (only if 1 search result is needed).

Answer (score 3):

```
**strong text**elif x.upper()=="Y":
k=input("Enter the 1st letter of the name (upper-Case):")
y=open("Names.txt","r")
found = False
for i in y.readlines():
    if k.upper() in i:
        print (i[:-1])
        found = True
if not found:
    print("no results")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**strong text**elif x.upper()=="Y":
    k=input("Enter the 1st letter of the name (upper-Case):")
    y=open("Names.txt","r")
    all_lines = y.readlines()
    for i in all_lines:
        if k.upper() in i:
            print (i[:-1])
        #need option if no search results are found
    found_f = k.upper() in ''.join(all_lines)
```

You can search the entire file in one shot. Not the best performance, but simple enough to do.  That was trying to minimize changes to your code. I would do:

```
**strong text**elif x.upper()=="Y":
    k=input("Enter the 1st letter of the name (upper-Case):")
    y=open("Names.txt","r")
    all_text = y.read()
    for i in all_text.splitlines():
        if k.upper() in i:
            print (i) # don't need [:-1] anymore
        #need option if no search results are found
    found_f = k.upper() in all_text
```